# Dynamic css content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Today I have a tab bar that looks like this :

https://codepen.io/cdemez/pen/WNrQpWp

```
stuffs like width: 400px; etc...
```

If you look at the code, all the sizes are static :-(
So, I have several sizing issues:

1. Sometimes I have 4 buttons, sometimes 5
2. On some mobiles (ie. iPhone 5/SE) the bar is going out of the screen :-(

So, I wish to know if there is a way to fix this.

Mainly the second issue, when the screen is too small for the bar, then everything should by dynamically resized to match the screen size.

Any idea ?

Comment: Research the term **responsive design** -- And `@media` is going to be your friend.

Comment: Iphone 5s would be 360px width. So you have to adjust your width accordingly using media queries. You have used flex-shrink :0;  So those widths would not shrink, try removing those flex-shrink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple of changes to your code pen to get this to work. Mainly setting the width and max-width of each menu item `width: 10vw; max-width: 65x;`. So when the screen is small it will use the visual width "vw" up to when it hits 65px, then it will use that.

```js
$(".mobilebar-tab-item").click(function () {
  $(".mobilebar-tab-item").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".mobilebar-tab-overlay").css({
    left: $(this).prevAll().length * 65 + "px"
  });
});
```

```css
.mobilebar-container {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 15px;
        z-index: 12;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }

    .mobilebar-tab {
        height: 40px;
        width: fit-content;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
        border-radius: 6px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 10px solid #fff;
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        bottom: 0px;
    }

    .mobilebar-tab-item {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      width: 5vw;
        max-width: 65px;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }

        .mobilebar-tab-item.active {
            width: 10vw;
        max-width: 105px;
        }

    .mobilebar-tab-overlay {
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 10vw;
        max-width: 105px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .mobilebar-tab__icon {
        display: block;
        color: #F96972;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        line-height: 1;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">

<div class="mobilebar-container mobile-layout">
    <nav class="mobilebar-tab">

        <div class="mobilebar-tab-item active">
            <span class="mobilebar-tab__icon">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="mobilebar-tab-item">
            <span class="mobilebar-tab__icon">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
      
        <div class="mobilebar-tab-item">
            <span class="mobilebar-tab__icon">
                <i class="fab fa-themeco"></i>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="mobilebar-tab-item">
            <span class="mobilebar-tab__icon">
                <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="mobilebar-tab-item">
            <span class="mobilebar-tab__icon">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="mobilebar-tab-overlay"></div>
    </nav>
  
</div>
```

Comment: you're close to the solution, interesting technique. The main problem I have now is that the "overlay" is not placed correctly on the button. It is when the screen is small, but with a large screen there is an offset. It seems related to the "65px" hardcoded in the JS ! Any idea to solve this last step ?

Comment: BTW, I have updated my code with some fixes to get exactly what I'm looking for. But I wish to have a max width of 400px for the bar. How can I manage this ?

Answer (score -1):

You could use max/min width properties instead, that way it changes size of that entire bar depending on screen. You can also set a media query so that once it hits, say 700px it will change the size of that button. You can then use flexbox in the parent container itself and try setting it to flex-wrap: wrap; so the items drop to a new row.
If none of that works the way you want, then you can set the size of the font/icons using vw instead, while using max/min width on the bar. Experiment with those and see if they help give the results you need.